# Distinguish between collision surface orientations in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, box2d

I've been working on an iOS project, using Cocos2D 1.0 and Box2D, and I've run into a bit of a problem.

What I need to be able to do is determine the orientation of a surface my player has hit. For example, if we have a rectangular platform, and the player collides with it, I need to know whether the player has hit the left, right, top, or bottom face of it. ALL the objects in the game are square, and the ONLY one moving is the player.

I'm currently using a b2ContactListener in Box2D (well, my own subclass of one, anyway), and have been playing around with the local normal of the manifold from the contact in BeginContact. The main problem I have is that that normal seems to be affected by the rotation of the player body (e.g. the player has rotated 90 degrees, OR the player is spinning wildly on impact - both situations are giving me trouble), and I seem to end up with ambiguity (i.e. collisions with different faces that give the same normal...) if I try to allow for that - although of course I could just be doing something horribly wrong. Now, I don't understand manifolds very well, so it's possible that my problem stems from that, or maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Any suggestions?
I would prefer to do this in the cleanest and least ugly manner possible. Bear in mind that the main categorisation I care about is "player is landing on something from above" vs "everything else", but I may end up needing the exact 
If you need more information or clarification about anything, just ask.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am aware that the normal points from A to B (in a collision between A and B) by convention in Box2D, and my code does check to see which one is the player and takes this into account before doing any calculations to determine which face has been hit.

Comment: Can't you just look at the player's position relative to the contact point?

Comment: If you have a suggestion as to how to handle a) two contact points (polygon-on-polygon collisions can and frequently do result in this) and b) weird cases such as if the player is spinning and collides with a corner of a platform, then yes. I'll give it a shot anyway, but case handling might get a bit messy...

Comment: try looking at b2Manifold (b2Contact has it as it's field)

Comment: I assumed using the either the contact manifold or the world manifold to get the contact point(s) was obvious since that's how I'm getting the normal...

Comment: Use different fixture for player(leftHalf,Righthalf) and use contact listener to find which part of the player hit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I feel a little awkward about answering my own question, but apparently it's officially encouraged.

Anyway, the problem with the way I was approaching things was twofold. Firstly, I was using the contact manifold's local normal instead of the world normal. Secondly, my code for reversing the object transformations was buggy (I would never have needed to do this if I had been using the world manifold).

The world manifold takes into account object transformations and sizes and as such contains data more easily applicable to the world co-ordinate system.

By convention in Box2d, the collision normal (for both the world manifold and the contact manifold) points from A to B - this has to be taken into account for some uses, since the normal from A to B is the inverse of the normal from B to A, so you can't just assume that one body will always be A.

So, the solution is to use get the world manifold for each collision, examine its normal, and then make whatever decisions you want to make.

For example, in the `BeginContact` method of a b2ContactListener subclass (if you have no idea what I'm talking about then check out [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22) of this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12)):

```
void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
    contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold); // this method calls b2WorldManifold::Initialize with the appropriate transforms and radii so you don't have to worry about that
    b2Vec2 worldNormal = worldManifold.normal;
    // inspect it or do whatever you want based on that...  
}
```

Since you'll likely need to check what bodies are colliding, and which one is A and which one is B, you may want to keep a vector of structs containing the fixtures that collided (as in that [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22)) and the normal, and iterate over the vector in your `tick()` method or similar. (You can get these out of the contact with `contact->GetFixtureA()` and `contact->GetFixtureB()`.)

Now, you *could* get the point data from the world manifold, and make your decisions based on that, but why would you when the normal is already available, since in this *particular* case the normal (combined with which shapes the normal points from and to) is all that is needed.

---

**Edit (for @iBradApps):**

First, I'm assuming here that you have followed the tutorial I linked to and have a contact listener set up. If you haven't, follow it because Ray explains it in depth quite well.

Second, I want to point out that there is no absolute guarantee which object is A and which is B (well, it depends on what kind of Box2D objects they are; suffice to say if they can both move, you can't guarantee the ordering, at least as far as I know), so in my case I wanted to see if the player object had hit something, so I created a class variable (`b2Fixture *playerF`) in my contact listener that stored a reference to the player object so I could determine whether contact A or contact B was the player.

You asked about detecting a collision where something else collided with the top of B. Something like the following should work, although I haven't had a chance to test it for you:

In your ContactListener.h:

```
public:
    b2Fixture *playerF;
    // along with the vector etc mentioned in Ray's tutorial
    // and anything else you want
```

When you make the ContactListener in your `init()` (assuming you called it `_contactListener`):

```
_contactListener->playerF = playerFixture; // or whatever you called the player body fixture
```

`BeginContact` method:

```
void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
    contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold); // this method calls b2WorldManifold::Initialize with the appropriate transforms and radii so you don't have to worry about that
    b2Vec2 worldNormal = worldManifold.normal; // this points from A to B

    if (playerF == contact->GetFixtureA()) {

        // note that +ve y-axis is "up" in Box2D but down in OpenGL and Cocos2D
        if (worldNormal.y < -0.707) { // use a constant for performance reasons

            // if the y component is less than -1/sqrt(2) (approximately -0.707),
            // then the normal points more downwards than across, so A must be hitting B 
            // from roughly above. You could tune this more towards the top by increasing 
            // towards -1 if you want but it worked fine for me like this last time and 
            // you might run into issues with missing hits


            NSLog(@"Player (A) hit B roughly on the top side!");

            // here you can set any class variables you want to check in 
            // your update()/tick(), such as flags for whether the player has died from
            // falling or whatever
    }

    } else if (playerF == contact->GetFixtureB()) {

        if (worldNormal.y > 0.707) {

            NSLog(@"Player (B) hit A roughly on the top side!");
        }

    } else {
    // it's something else hitting something else and we don't care about it
    }
}
```

As for doing it in your `tick()` method instead, yes, you can. I actually did all my stuff in `PostSolve` in the contact listener because I needed to know how hard the player hit, but all I cared about beyond that was whether the player had hit hard enough to kill them, so I didn't need or want to iterate over all the contacts in my `tick()` - I just set a flag in the contact listener that said the player had suffered a fatal impact.

If you want to do this all in the update method, then starting from what Ray has, add a `b2Vec2` to the MyContact struct, and in `BeginContact`, add both the two fixtures (like Ray does) *and* get the collision normal (as I do) and add it too.

The modified `MyContact` struct:

```
struct MyContact {
    b2Fixture *fixtureA;
    b2Fixture *fixtureB;
    b2Vec2 normal;
    bool operator==(const MyContact& other) const
    {
        return (fixtureA == other.fixtureA) && (fixtureB == other.fixtureB);
    }
};
```

The new `BeginContact` method:

```
void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
    b2WorldManifold wordManifold;
    contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold);

    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB(), worldManifold.normal };
    _contacts.push_back(myContact);
}
```

This will give you all the information you need to do the checking I initially described in your `tick()`.

---

**Edit again:**
Your `tick()` method might contain something like this if you want to do the processing there, assuming you have called the player fixture (or ball fixture, like in the tutorial, or whatever it is you're interested in) _playerFixture, that you've got a contact listener with the same name as in the tutorial, that you added the b2Vec2 normal to the MyContact struct, that you are adding contacts to the vector (as above) in BeginContact, and that you are deleting contacts from the vector in the EndContact (as shown in the tutorial - it's probably fine as is):

```
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
    MyContact contact = *pos;
    if (_playerFixture == contact.fixtureA && contact.normal.y < -0.707) {
            NSLog(@"Player (A) hit B roughly on the top side!");
    } else if (_playerFixture == contact.fixtureB && contact.normal.y > 0.707) {
            NSLog(@"Player (B) hit A roughly on the top side!");
    } else {
    // it's something else hitting something else and we don't care about it
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this old question back but I need to accomplish the same thing. If I am not troubling you, would you mind expanding the code in this answer to say detect if 'fixtureB' was collided with on the top? I would be very thankful! Also I up voted both the question and the answer :P

Comment: @iBradApps Sure, although I'm at work right now so I'll edit it tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a few more questions and I hate wasting your time so I will give you a bounty when I get this working! :) Anyway, 1. With the code above, can you add a check if it is fixtureA and then reverse the < to > depending on that check? I just can't see how I would do that (sorry!) 2. Is there any way to move this code to the tick method? Specifically if you look at that tutorial 2 in the Destroying the blocks section, the code under that. Can I move these checks there since I think it would be easier on my end for that? Thats all my questions for now! Let me know!!! :)

Comment: @iBradApps 1) Added. 2) Yes, see what I added :D

Comment: Thank you! I'll test this later or tomorrow and will let you know! Thanks again.

Comment: Update, I started going throw your answer and code and I have ran into an issue. I am really confused on how the tick method (the destroying the blocks code from tut) should look since it is a different class than the MyContactListener class. Can you just show how that tick method would look then along with the Begin Contact method code? Everything you are doing now in the Begin Contact method, I need to do in my tick method and some things are not there like the b2Contact. If you could just show how that tick method should look I think I will be good from there.Also I added the bounty,Thanks!

Comment: You can't do absolutely everything in the tick - you still need to use the contact listener's `BeginContact` and `EndContact` to add/remove contacts to/from the vector that you iterate over in `tick()`. Anyway, added more detail in the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you! It works pretty good (much better than my technique before :P). I decided that instead of checking for matching fixtures, I just went with tags because I find them easier. Last and final question, how should I modify the 0.707 number so that it accepts a bit wider angle than it is now?

Comment: Also along with my comment above, if there is any mac program that can help me visualize how big of an angle that i want and then calculate the value, let me know!!! :P

Comment: Just increase the number towards 1.0. I don't know of any programs that can visualise it for you, but you can use cosine(angle_in_degrees) where angle is the from the vertical to each side (e.g. \|/). ~0.707 is cos(45degrees). 1 is cos(0degrees)

Comment: Ok thank you for everything so far! I awarded you the bounty, and up voted your answer. And just to clarify what did you mean by "the vertical" and "the side" of lets say a square. What point of the square were you talking about? I just wanted to properly visualize it in my head.

Comment: No problem, and thanks. I mean the angle between the vertical plane and the collision normal. Say A is a square, and B is a rectangle. If A lands on top of B, the collision normal from A to B will point straight down, so the angle between the collision normal and a vertical line is zero. Now, imagine B is a circle and A doesn't land perfectly on top of it. The collision normal from A to B will not be pointing straight down any more. The angle between it and a vertical line won't be zero anymore.

Comment: If you're using 0.707 for the comparison, then we're considering it to be a collision where A landed (roughly) "on top" of B if the angle is 45 degrees or less (we are determining this by looking at the size of the y component of the collision normal, which will always have a total length of 1 since it is a unit vector).

Comment: Ok thanks that explains it. After some testing, even if I put 1 for both possible collisions, it still seems the angle is very small from the side it can land on. Take a look at this image that I made: http://imgur.com/t1Elu I pretty much want the bottom of the character to be to touch the green areas and it will count as a collision and the red part it will not count as a collision. I think your code already does all of this, I am just trying to find the right value but I just don't know what. Maybe that picture will help you understand what I am trying to achieve exactly! Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I'm so sorry. I said to increase it towards 1 because I thought you wanted a smaller angle. Totally misread one of your comments. Decrease the values towards 0. Don't make them too low though. Also, it might be very, very hard to get it exactly the way you want it - those little bits of side you have highlighted are likely to be a pain.

Comment: Ok I will do some more trial and error tomorrow and I will let you know. Thanks for all of the help so far!

Comment: Okay, I managed to have time to do some testing. Even if I go down to the .100 to .200 range it still does not accept most collision from the side that are very close to the top. It makes it much harder for the player to land on the floor so I want to make it a bit easier. So is it possible to achieve the area that I highlighted from that picture?

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of the normal to see what it's doing?

Comment: Yes when I am directly on top of the floor with the character it logs: -1.000000. If I am coming in from the side from an angle which it doesn't accept but I want it to, it logs: -0.002030

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't surprise me - the collision normal will be mostly horizontal in the latter case, _just like if it hit further down the side_. You could try making the corners of the box rounded (if possible). Getting this to work will be really tricky. IMO the best solution is not to do it. Instead, make the Box2D object you want the player to land (floor/platform/whatever) a little bit shorter and maybe a fraction wider than the sprite/image representing the ground. This is a pretty common adjustment so that it feels more forgiving. http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2774/box2dexample.png

Comment: That's a good idea, let me try that and I will get back to you!

Comment: Do you know of any good program that can help me get the specific values to accomplish something like the picture you showed me? Just doing trial and errors seems like it will take forever! :P P.S - How did you make that image, what program did you use?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything off the top of my head. Yeah, trial and error is a pain but sometimes it is the only way. I made that image using www.pixlr.com

Comment: Sorry for the lack of updates, I finally was able to get back to this issue. The program I am using is Physics Editor. I am implementing the custom shapes today or within the next few days and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was able to get all the shapes working nicely with Physics Editor. Now my last issue with collision detection is trying to get the collision point between the b2Bodys. Is this possible? Have you ever tried to do something like this? If so, I can give you another bounty if you show me!

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. What do you mean when you say the collision point between the bodies? Do you mean the area of contact between the two bodies (it won't always be just a point)...

Comment: Yes the collision area but TBH I think instead of doing this which will be complicated, I will just roll my own system of determining the Y collision value.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, the world manifold (think of it as kind of like an area for now) should contain an array of contact points (`b2Vec2`s). `worldManifold.points` is the array.

Comment: Also, I think (haven't tested) `worldManifold.m_pointCount` provides the number of points, although you shouldn't see more than two, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I remember doing this then getting the Y point somehow. However, the Y point never changed during the collision even though it should have been clearly changing. It was stagnant at around 311 if I remember correctly.

Comment: I suggest you try again - the behaviour you're describing sounds wrong. Just start by using NSLog to print out the x and y coordinates of any points the array during a collision, and confirm whether or not you are seeing any changes.