# Box2D collision manifold?

Tags: vector, box2d, collision, chipmunk

I have seen around that there is a b2Manifold. What I want to accomplish is to detect whether or not a collision was on the top part or not of one of the objects that were colliding.

I have already set up a b2ContactListener and it works fine. I would just like to provide more accurate collisions by setting up the manifold to detect if one b2Body is on top of the other b2Body that it collided with.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

http://postimage.org/image/kbfr7c5db/

Comment: Look into 'collision manifolds'. You can get these from the contact listener functions, and check the normal there, but it's not all that straightforward. This might help http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

Comment: Wow that is quite difficult. If I gave you a bounty of 50 points, would you show me the exact code I need to see if a CCSprite with a b2Body attached to it landed on top of another CCSprite with a b2Body also attached to that. Currently I am only using Ray Wenderlich's tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22 ... And I have that part working, I just need to figure out this.

Comment: I don't know anything about CC stuff sorry. Maybe it would be enough to just look at the positions of the bodies when they collided?

Comment: Positions meaning point wise? They are constantly moving so that would be out of the picture unfortunately unless you meant something else.

Comment: Positions as in body->GetPosition() when they collide. You mean you want to continuously track when something is above or below? I guess you could look at the location of the manifold's point in relation to the body. Better still, you could put a sensor fixture on the body in the appropriate locations and use the contact listener to know when the sensor is touching something - this is the recommended way. See the "Can I jump question" topic on my site there. The sensor can be anywhere on the body and you can have more than one, eg. http://tinyurl.com/83jyvzh

Comment: Okay I will do so. One last question, do sensors have positions? Could I check if one sensor is above the other? Because there is still a chance I could hit the sensor from the side.

Comment: You can make the sensor whatever shape you need to prevent it from being hit from the side. It could be a tiny little circle or a huge box, and you can have a bunch of them.

Comment: Im confused. With any shape, it is able to be hit from the side so why would it matter? I was also looking at this question (he is was trying to accomplish the same as I am trying to): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459208/distinguish-between-collision-surface-orientations-in-box2d

Comment: Could you show some examples of the shapes you are using, and the cases you would like to distinguish.

Comment: I have also made an image explaining what I want to do, I added the link to the question above.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about one-way platforms? This might help http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/one-way-walls

Comment: That link seems to do exactly what I want. Although there are many things in there that are confusing me. Like the velocity values and so forth. I do not use any velocity values in Box2D that's why it's confusing. If you can post the relevant code without those confusing velocity values, I'll accept your answer and up vote it! Thanks for all the help so far!!! :)

Comment: Sorry dude. The relevant code is on that page and it doesn't come without velocity values... like you said, your positions will be constantly moving.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, I will look into it more!